# Flutter getx: Loop happen in login midelware

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am using Getx on my sample project like this:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      initialRoute: AppLinks.LOGIN,
      getPages: AppRoutes.pages,
      initialBinding: MainBinding(),
    );
  }
}
```

I have this routes:

```
class AppRoutes {
  static final pages = [
    GetPage(
      name: AppLinks.LOGIN,
      page: () => Login(),
      binding: LoginBinding(),
    ),
    GetPage(
      name: AppLinks.DASHBOARD,
      page: () => Dashboard(),
      middlewares: [
        AuthGuard(),
      ],
      children: [...
```

as you can see I declared a middelwares:

```
  middlewares: [
    AuthGuard(),
  ],
```

This is a simple midelware:

```
class AuthGuard extends GetMiddleware {
  final authService = Get.find<AuthService>();

  @override
  int? get priority => 1;

  @override
  RouteSettings? redirect(String? route) {
    if (authService.isAuthenticated)
      return RouteSettings(name: AppLinks.LOGIN);
    else
      return RouteSettings(name: AppLinks.DASHBOARD);
  }
}
```

Inside Loginpage I have a button:

```
ElevatedButton(
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    primary: Colors.red,
    onPrimary: Colors.green,
    onSurface: Colors.pink,
  ),
  onPressed: () => controller.toDashboard(),
  child: Text("Dashboard"),
)
```

and inside it's controller I have this:

```
class LoginController extends GetxController {
  toDashboard() => Get.toNamed(AppLinks.DASHBOARD);
}
```

But when I call `toDashboard` method I get into loop in this statement:

```
  @override
  RouteSettings? redirect(String? route) {
    if (authService.isAuthenticated)
      return RouteSettings(name: AppLinks.LOGIN);
    else
      return RouteSettings(name: AppLinks.DASHBOARD);
  }
}
```

I am using:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  get: ^4.3.4
```

and doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) 4.19.0-18-amd64, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] Android Studio
[✓] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you want to send users to LoginPage if the user `isAuthenticated`?
Or the opposite?

You need to change this:

```
  if(authService.isAuthenticated)
  return RouteSettings(name: AppLinks.LOGIN);
  else
  return RouteSettings(name: AppLinks.DASHBOARD);
```

to this:

```
if(!authService.isAuthenticated)
  return RouteSettings(name: AppLinks.LOGIN);
  else
  return RouteSettings(name: AppLinks.DASHBOARD);
```

Comment: No difference I still  fall in the loop @S. M. JAHANGIR

Answer (score 0):

No redirect needed if you are authenticated, see
https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx#redirect

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

No redirect needed if you are authenticated, see https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx#redirect

You need to change this:

```
if(authService.isAuthenticated)
  return RouteSettings(name: AppLinks.LOGIN);
  else
  return RouteSettings(name: AppLinks.DASHBOARD);
```

to this:

```
return (!authService.isAuthenticated)
        ? const RouteSettings(name: AppLinks.LOGIN)
        : null;
```